# Counterexample or proof for the given inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inequality, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Let $p, x_i \in \mathbb{R^m}$, $ (i=1,..,n) $ 
with  $||x_i||=||p||=1$ for all $i$.

Suppose that $p$ satisfies $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{arccos}(\langle p,x_i\rangle) \:\leq\: \sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{arccos}(\langle u,x_i\rangle)$$
$\forall u\in \mathbb{R^m}, ||u||=1$

I believe that this implies the following inequality:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle p,x_i\rangle  \geq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle u,x_i\rangle  \forall u\in \mathbb{R^m}, ||u||=1$

My reasons:

- $0 \leq |\langle p,x_i\rangle| \leq 1 $ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)
- $\text{arccos}:[-1,1] \rightarrow [0,\pi] $ is bijective and strictly decreasing

How do you prove this inequality? Or is there a contradiction?

Comment: Have you done some simulations? It seems not true.

Comment: Yes, I did some simulations for m=3 and p seemed to satisfy both inequalities. That´s actually how I came up with this conjecture. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: First, $n=m=2$, $x_1 = [-\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{3}{5}]^T$ and $x_2 = [-1, 0]^T$. $p_0=[-1, 0]^T$ is a minimizer of $\min \sum \arccos (p^Tx_i)$. Then $\sum p_0^Tx_i = 1.8$ but $\sum u^Tx_i > 1.8$ for $u=[0.9, \sqrt{1-0.9^2}]^T$. Please check it.